# How do I host a WASM file on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, web-hosting, webassembly

I have created a Blazor WebAssembly application and published it in Visual Studios. Now my task is to push the Release folder of the application into the Raspberry Pi and host the application from the Raspberry Pi on the internet. I would like to know the solution to this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use nginx as a web server, but apache works too.
Just set one up and go through the Microsoft documentation.

[Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#nginx)

[Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#nginx)